# Open source multi tenant campaign management & fund management web platform?

Tags: open-source, framework

Recently, we try to update our nonprofitable organization web site, it is a small but global NGO, the best requirement include:

- **support multi tenant**, since we have different sub organization at different region / country, it is important for each individual to be managed individually (better with its own domain name, but back end support by one platform).
- **support multiple language**, it is critical for local organization to use its own language.
- **each regional organization can add / remove some module, and manage its own members**, we assume some of the core module will be mandatory, but other can be optional.

The **core function should include**:

- member management, regional admin, potential member management
- campaign management, fund management
- member support, etc.

If you know what may be good existing open source platform which can support some or most of those, please share your thoughts here. The preferred language is Java, but will consider other languages, such as PHP, Python, C#, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, Mark! I took the freedom to slightly re-format your question, to make it easier to catch the "core keywords". Any limitations when it comes to the underlying operating system, or the web server used? That might be important points to add. Please, [edit] your question to include those facts (even if it means "no limitations, as we run multiple servers" ;)

Comment: Could you please describe "campaign management, fund management" in more details? It sounds like it is your most business-specific requirement.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul "Campaign management" refer to fund raise event, it is to raise the fund to donate to the third party (NGO) for certain events (such as disaster recovery, etc). "Fund management" refer to the management of the fund raised from the campaign or other donation. It is very common practice for NGO to do campaign management and fund management, actually, IRS will audit the NGO for its fund activity.

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) should be able to accommodate this.

- *multi-tenancy:* (includes allowing each org/site to have its own plugins, etc.) built-in since v3.0 (was called "WordPress MU" before that):  http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
- *multi-lingual:* many plugins listed at http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

The rest of your core functionality can also be handled by a number of [WordPress plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of installing or maintaining [CiviCRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CiviCRM), but it seems specifically designed to handle use-cases like yours. For example, quoting mainly from the [features](https://civicrm.org/go/features) page:

- **support multi-tenant**: "create multiple membership levels for multiple organizations and/or chapters".
- **support multiple languages**: "[Internationalization and localization](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88408149) make it possible to use CiviCRM in languages and cultural environments other than American English."
- **each regional organization can add / remove some module, and manage its own members**: "customize membership statuses and rules".
- **campaign management**: "register volunteers for projects using events registration feature".
- **fund management**: "allow campaign fundraising".

It is free and open-source software, licensed under the AGPLv3, and written in PHP.